# Is it necessary to do Core Data reads within performBlock when using NSMainQueueConcurrencyType?

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency

According to Daniel Eggert's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637921/core-datas-nsprivatequeueconcurrencytype-and-sharing-objects-between-threads), when using a managed object context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` it's necessary to do *anything* that touches it or objects that belong to it within `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`

Is the same true for `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`? Imagine the following code running on the main thread, in a UIViewController for instance:

```
self.moc = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease];
//moc setup

__block RHWidget *widget = nil;

[self.moc performBlockAndWait:^{
    widget = [(RHWidget *)[self.moc objectWithID:self.widgetObjectID] retain];
}];

self.labelView.text = widget.descriptionString;

[widget release];
```

Is it safe to use the widget outside the block, since we know we're on the main thread? Or it is it necessary to do this:

```
__block NSString *description = nil;

[self.moc performBlockAndWait:^{
    RHWidget *widget = (RHWidget *)[self.moc objectWithID:self.widgetObjectID];
    description = [widget.descriptionString copy];
}];

self.labelView.text = description;

[description release];
```

Do things change if there's another `NSManagedObjectContext` out there, possibly of the private queue type, doing work in blocks and pushing changes up to self.moc as a `parentContext`?

This is a slightly contrived example of course, but it'd be nice to safely pass that widget to, for instance, a modal view controller that needs to access some of the widget's properties. Should I be passing the objectID of the widget instead and refetching it within `performBlock:` in the new view controller?

Comment: There is a very comprehensive article [here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/) which describes the various approaches including context concurrency types and nested contexts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** According to [WWDC 2011 Session 303 (What's New in Core Data on iOS)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/), `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` is intended to allow normal messaging on the main thread; you only need to use `-performBlock:` when interacting with the context from a different thread. (Still-relevant parts of my original answer below.)

---

I've made an app or two that modifies Xcode's default "Master-Detail" app template to make the "main" MOC (created by the app delegate and passed among view controllers) main-queue-only, and parent to a private-queue context that I use for background operations like importing data from a web fetch. Thus, most uses of the context and its objects happen without being wrapped in `performBlock:`. (The only time I do use `performBlock:` is to push changes from the background-task context back to the main one to update the UI.) Works just fine.

Comment: That's more or less what I'm doing; I've got a singleton with an  `NSOperationQueue` and a context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` that gets passed to each operation. Those operations fetch objects, do their work, save the local context, then save the parent context, all within `performBlock:`. Everything seems to work okay, but I'm worried about an unforeseen race condition or memory management gotcha.

Comment: @roland. I don't think this is a safe method because a NSOperationQueue can use several threads (even if its maxConcurrentOperationCount is 1). When you are using parent/child context mecanism you will have less concurrency problems because it's always the parent context that access the store.