# How can I acquire a snapshot of model objects fetched in a NSManagedObjectContext, so they are available after the context is deallocated?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm interested in writing a method which returns an object of class `Document`, according to some query about the document's name.

`Document` happens to subclass `NSManagedObject`, but the consumer doesn't really care about that. The `Document` object is successfully faulted inside the method, and its properties are accessible. However, once the method is left and the `NSManagedObjectContext` used for the fetch is deallocated, the object once again turns into a fault.

Is there a way to detach the `NSManagedObject` from its context, so it doesn't turn into a fault? Of course this would not allow saving changes to the object, but I'm not interested in that anyway.

I would hate to resort to either:

1. Writing a `NonManagedDocument` class which mirrors the `Document` class.
2. Tagging along with an `NSManagedObjectContext` for as long as I'm interested in the Documents. The consumer doesn't care and doesn't have to be aware of the fact that `Document` subclasses `NSManagedObject`.

**Note:**

I would add that even if I *were* able to keep the `Document` after the `NSManagedObjectContext`, it wouldn't be a great solution, since a consumer *would* have access to the `Document`s interface as an `NSManagedObjectContext` subclass, which is undesirable as it may lead to unexpected bugs. But the alternative of manually having to write a freeze-dry wrapper for each model object which happens to be stored in the DB is very unattractive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - `NSManagedObjects` always remain bound to their context in the Core Data stack. Which makes sense.

One possible solution would be to write something similar to [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator), but which automatically creates non-managed snapshot classes, and methods on the managed classes which create these copies.

Alternatively, there might be some obj-C trick to generate `NSManagedObjects` subclasses which retain their context, *and* hide the fact that they subclass `NSManagedObject`, so consumers are only exposed to the snapshotted properties and not to the whole `NSManagedObject` functionality.

Answer (score 3):

`NSManagedObject`s are tightly bounds to the Core Data stack. The entities aren't necessarily fully loaded in memory, and the relationships are most certainly not. So well, as far as I know, there is no supported way to do what you're asking for.

You described the alternatives you have pretty well. Sorry to hear you hate them. ;)

That said, it is possible to generate the mirroring classes at runtime, you do not have to write and maintain every single entity manually. The ObjC runtime allows us to do some fancy things.

---

edit: some snippets toward NSDictionary snapshots

```
NSManagedObject* any; // let's imagine you have an instance at hand
NSAttributeDescription* entityDescription = any.entity;

// Attributes
NSDictionary* attributeDescriptions = entityDescription.attributesByName;
for ( NSAttributeDescription* attributeDescription in attributeDescriptions.allValues )
{
    NSString* attributeName = attributeDescription.name;
    NSAttributeType attributeType = attributeDescription.attributeType;
    Class attributeClass = NSClassFromString( attributeDescription.attributeValueClassName );

    …
    id attributePrimeValue = [any primitiveValueForKey: attributeName];
    id attributeValue = [any valueForKey: attributeName];
    …

}

// Relationships
NSDictionary* relationshipDescriptions = entityDescription.relationshipsByName;
for ( NSRelationshipDescription* relationshipDescription in relationshipDescriptions.allValues )
{
    …
}
```

With this as a starting point, you should be able to iterate over the attributes, get their name, type and value, and create NSDictionary based snapshots. Relationships are iterated the same, but of course what you'll do with the relation is tightly bound to your needs.

Comment: Any available mirroring solution? A lot of things are possible in ObjC, but cost time. Also it's obvious that detaching from the NSManagedObjectContext doesn't make sense for unfaulted relationships etc. However I'm just interested in a simple case of getting the attributes of a faulted object, without having to write a mirror class for each entity.

Comment: I do not know about a snapshots library out there, but I added some code to help you getting started.

Comment: I'm not interested in forcing all Core Data consumers to have to work with `NSDictionaries` instead of statically known classes. This would be similar to working with `NSManagedObjects` directly instead of creating a subclass for each entity - Possible, but cumbersome, less safe, not as readable/testable etc.

Comment: Understood. I was about to suggest for the next step to provide a shell class, using the dictionary above as a store and providing dynamically generated methods for every attribute in the dictionary. But it seems you have no other choice than to provide statically declared classes. It's possible to generate them automatically based on the Core Data model, but that requirement of yours rules out every possible runtime solution.

Answer (score 3):

I really do not understand your problem.  If you expose a class that inherits from NSManagedObject, then the user of that class has that imposition, along with the accompanying issues.

If you expose your class as a composition, the details of the managed object is within the class, and those details can easily be hidden.

You can certainly create/destroy MOCs when you want, they are pretty cheap.  However, that does not seem to be super beneficial.

I would suggest keeping a single managed object context that you use for your interface.  You mentioned worrying about multiple threads calling into the MOC.  That's a valid concern, but easily, and efficiently, overcome by using a MOC with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType.

Then, anytime you need to fetch your object, you simply do

```
[moc performBlockAndWait:^{
    // Fetch the object from the MOC
}];
```

Be careful calling the synchronous version because you have the possibility of deadlocking.

Alternatively, you can still use your option of creating a unique context for each fetch...

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
moc.parentContext = myPrivateQueueContext;
// Now, you can fetch from this MOC, and do what you want with the object
// and when you are done, you just let the MOC dealloc.
```

You may want to look at the options for NSFetchRequest, and also settings on the MOC itself, specifically

```
refreshObject:mergeChanges:
retainsRegisteredObjects
```

If you tell myPrivateQueueContext to retain objects, it will keep them in its local MOC.  Then, when you perform your fetch, you can tell the fetch to prefer the cached version in the MOC, and it will never even go to disk.

You can gain further advantages if you store the objectID of the managed object, and just call  objectRegisteredForID: which just looks for already registered objects.
whoever downvoted the answer
You can then manually clean your cache, so it does not get too big, if you need to do that.

Or, you can call existingObjectWithID:error: which will never return a fault.  The result will always be a realized object or nil.

Anyway, I think what you want to do can be easily solved in a number of ways.  I would caution you, though, not to over-engineer your solution.

Figure out what interface you want to expose, and implement that.  If you later discover performance issues, deal with them at that time.

** EDIT **

Specifically to address Danra's comment (and also whoever downvoted the answer).  I never intended for you to access the data directly from the private MOC.  If you want to access the private MOC, use performBlock.

However, you can create as many children as you want... of any concurrency type, and use them to your heart's desire.  When they need to talk to the database, they will just talk directly to the parent (in the proper context).

Nothing I said suggested that you do anything with the private MOC, but call performBlock or make it a parent of another MOC.

Comment: I agree a per-thread or singleton managed object context is the way to go--this eliminates the issue.

Comment: "Figure out what interface you want to expose" - The required interface is for consumers to be able to get non-managed *copies* of Model objects, in the case where these objects are Core Data `NSManagedObject`s. The issue is how to implement this interface in a good, general way. (Without having to write a non-managed class for every entity). Regarding performance, I agree, and I'm not worried about it right now.

Comment: I believe your suggestion using NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType won't work properly - Managed objects fetched by a moc with a private queue still are only expected to be accessed on the moc's thread. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637921/core-datas-nsprivatequeueconcurrencytype-and-sharing-objects-between-threads

Answer (score 2):

Why not just hide the `NSManagedObjectContext`? Your consumer may not care about the fact that is is a `NSManagedObject`, but they won't need to use the `NSManagedObjectContext`, it'd be your implementation detail. You should never need to expose the `NSManagedObjectContext` and just use one for all of your documents.

Comment: The documents fetching method can be called from any thread. Your solution forces saving an `NSManagedObjectContext` object indefinitely for every calling thread (With each context possibly outliving its calling thread!)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are deallocating the managed object context.  Why not setup the Core Data stack in the app delegate so you can access your NSManagedObjects from anywhere in the program?

If you need to perform background tasks make sure to create one NSManagedObjectContext on the main thread (in app delegate) and create another NSManagedObjectContext in a background thread.

You may want to check into Magical Record (https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/) to assist with greatly simplifying working with Core Data AND properly managing contexts on multiple threads.

Comment: I'll take a look at Magical Panda. Regarding your other suggestion, see my answer to @hypercrypt.

Comment: Danra, I read your answer to @hypercrypt.  MagicalRecord manages away much of the frustration of normal core data.  I really think MR will resolve most if not all of your frustrations working with threads and contexts

Answer (score 2):

To build on @hypercrypt's answer: Why not just expose the fact that your API is based on managed object? This similar to what @jody proposes.

You could use a category on NSManagedObjectContext to handle getting a per-thread `NSManagedObjectContext`. Something like:

```
@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (PerThreadContext)

+(NSManagedObjectContext*)contextForCurrentThread
{
    static OSSpinLock lock = OS_SPINLOCK_INIT ;
    @try 
    {
        OSSpinLockLock( & lock ) ;

        NSDictionary * info = [ NSThread currentThread ].threadDictionary ;
        NSManagedObjectContext * context = [ info valueForKey:@"managedObjectContext" ] ;
        if ( !context )
        {
            context = [ [ NSManagedObjectContext alloc ] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType ] ;
            context.persistentStoreCoordinator = [ NSPersistentStoreCoordinator sharedCoordinator ] ; // perhaps a category we added to NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? Or use your app delegate, etc...
            [ info setObject:context forKey:@"managedObjectContext" ] ;
        }
    }
    @finally 
    {
        OSSpinLockUnlock( & lock ) ;
    }
    return context ;
}

@end
```

When one of your API methods is called:

```
-(NSManagedObject*)getSomeObject
{
    NSManagedObjectContext * context = [ NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread ] ;

    NSManagedObject * result = ....code...
    return result ;
}
```

Now, if you want to force immutability, you could add a category to NSManagedObject (or create a base class for your object graph instances)

As a category:

```
@interface NSManagedObject (Freezing)
@property ( nonatomic, readonly ) BOOL frozen ;
-(void)freeze ;
@end

@implementation NSManagedObject (Freezing)

-(void)setFrozen:(BOOL)f
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject( self, "_frozen", [ NSNumber numberWithBool:f ], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC ) ;
}

-(BOOL)frozen
{
   return [ objc_getAssociatedObject( self, "_frozen" ) boolValue ] ;
}

-(void)freeze
{
    [ self setFrozen:YES ] ;
}

-(BOOL)validateForUpdate:(NSError**)error
{
    if ( self.frozen ) 
    { 
        if ( error ) { *error = [ NSError ... ] ; }
        return NO ; 
    }

    return [ super validateForUpdate:error ] ;
}

-(BOOL)validateForDelete:(NSError**)error
{
    if ( self.frozen ) 
    { 
        if ( error ) { *error = [ NSError ... ] ; }
        return NO ; 
    }

    return [ super validateForDelete:error ] ;
}

@end
```

Finally, if you are dead set on tearing down your core data stack, I would add a `-(NSDictionary*)dictionaryRepresentation` category to NSManagedObject as use that to turn your managed objects into dictionaries you pass to your consumer. (You can see I like categories?)

For results returned from a core data fetch, use the `NSDictionaryResultType` result type on your fetch requests. This will return results as dictionaries.

HTH