# Multi-Context Core Data - Duplicate issues when importing from a background context

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I have a typical multi-context CoreData stack setup - A master MOC on a private queue (attached to the PSC), which has a child on the main queue and it used as the app's main context. Finally, bulk import operations (find-or-create) are passed off onto a third MOC using a background queue (new context created for each operation). Once the operation is complete saves are propagated up to the PSC.

I'd been suffering from issues where duplicate objects where being created, presumably because these operations were executing concurrently. Operation 1 would start. If an object didn't exist, it was created in Operation 1. At the same time Operation 2 is concurrently running. Because Operation 1 hadn't completed, Operation 2 couldn't possibly know about the newly created object, so it would also proceed to create a new object, hence the duplicates.

To resolve this, I funnelled all find-or-create operation into a serial `NSOperationQueue` to ensure that all operations are executed one at a time:

```
- (void) performBlock: (void(^)(Player *player, NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext)) operation onSuccess: (void(^)()) successCallback onError:(void(^)(id error)) errorCallback
{
    //Add this operation to the NSOperationQueue to ensure that 
    //duplicate records are not created in a multi-threaded environment
    [self.operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [managedObjectContext setUndoManager:nil];
        [managedObjectContext setParentContext:self.mainManagedObjectContext];

        [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{

            //Retrive a copy of the Player object attached to the new context
            id player = [managedObjectContext objectWithID:[self.player objectID]];
            //Execute the block operation
            operation(player, managedObjectContext);

            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
            {
                //Call the error handler
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                    if(errorCallback) return errorCallback(error);
                });
                return;
            }

            //Save the parent MOC (mainManagedObjectContext) - WILL BLOCK MAIN THREAD BREIFLY
            [managedObjectContext.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
                NSError *error = nil;
                if (![managedObjectContext.parentContext save:&error])
                {
                    //Call the error handler
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                        if(errorCallback) return errorCallback(error);
                    });
                    return;
                }
            }];

            //Attempt to clear any retain cycles created during operation
            [managedObjectContext reset];

            //Call the success handler
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (successCallback) return successCallback();
            });
        }];
    }];
}
```

My operation queue is simply configured as follows:

```
single.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[single.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

This does seem to have reduced the incidences of the duplicate issues quite significantly but to my surprise has not eliminated it entirely. The occurrences are much less frequent, but it still happens.

Can anyone enlighten me as to why this is still happening?

**UPDATE: Added additional code to describe what is happening in the `operation` block:**

```
- (void) importUpdates: (id) methodResult onSuccess: (void (^)()) successCallback onError: (void (^)(id error)) errorCallback
{
    [_model performBlock:^(Player *player, NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext) {
        //Player and Opponents
        NSMutableDictionary *opponents = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; //Store the opponents in a dict so we can do relationship fix-up later

        [player parseDictionary:methodResult[@"player"] inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

        for (NSDictionary *opponentDictionary in methodResult[@"opponents"])
        {
            Opponent *opponent = [Opponent updateOrInsertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext withDictionary:opponentDictionary];
            opponents[opponent.playerID] = opponent;
        }

        //Matches
        [self parseMatches: methodResult[@"matches"] withPlayer: player andOpponents: opponents usingManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

    } onSuccess:successCallback onError:errorCallback];
}
```

`parseMatches` contains an implementation of find-or-create:

```
- (NSArray *) parseMatches: (NSArray *) matchDictionaries withPlayer: (Player *) player andOpponents: (NSDictionary *) opponents usingManagedObjectContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
    NSMutableArray *parsedMatches = [NSMutableArray array];

    [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        //Sorted matchDictionaties
        NSArray *sortedMatchDictionaries = [matchDictionaries sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"matchID" ascending:YES]]];
        NSArray *sortedMatchIDsInResponse = [sortedMatchDictionaries valueForKeyPath:@"matchID"];

        //Fetch the existing matches
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Match"];
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(matchID IN %@)", sortedMatchIDsInResponse];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"matchID" ascending:YES]]];
        [fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:@[@"roundsSet", @"player", @"opponent"]];

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *existingMatches = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


        //Walk through the existing match array and the matches in the response
        int i=0,j=0,updated=0,added=0,skipped=0;
        while ((i < [sortedMatchDictionaries count]))
        {
            NSDictionary *matchDictionary = sortedMatchDictionaries[i];
            Match *match = j < [existingMatches count] ? existingMatches[j] : nil;

            NSLog(@"%@ %@", matchDictionary[@"matchID"], match.matchID);

            NSComparisonResult result = match ? [((NSString *)matchDictionary[@"matchID"]) compare: match.matchID] : NSOrderedDescending;

            if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            {
                //match exists in both, update
                NSLog(@"updated");

                [match parseDictionary:matchDictionary inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

                //Set the match opponent (as it may have been initally nil in the case of a random match)
                if (match.opponentID != nil && [opponents objectForKey:match.opponentID] != nil)
                {
                    [match setValue:opponents[match.opponentID] forKey:@"opponent"];
                }

                [parsedMatches addObject:match];
                i++,j++,updated++;
            }
            else if (result == NSOrderedDescending)
            {
                NSLog(@"added");

                //match doesnt exist on device, add
                Match *match = [Match insertNewObjectWithDictionary:matchDictionary inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

                //Set the match player and opponent
                if (match.opponentID != nil && [opponents objectForKey:match.opponentID] != nil)
                {
                    [match setValue:opponents[match.opponentID] forKey:@"opponent"];
                }
                [match setValue:player forKey:@"player"];

                [parsedMatches addObject:match];
                i++,added++;

            } else {
                NSLog(@"match %@ exists on device but not in response, skipping", match.matchID);
                j++;skipped++;
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"CORE DATA IMPORT: Inserted %u matches. Updated %u matches. Skipped %u matches", added, updated, skipped);
    }];

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:parsedMatches];
}
```

It's worth noting that once duplicate objects with the same `matchID` find their way into the store then this algorithm no longer works and the duplicates are proliferated. But that's not the problem I'm concerned about, it's the fact that duplicates are occurring in the first place.

**SECOND UPDATE:**

This is the stack trace to a crash I'm occasionally seeing that seems to occur just before the duplicates get into the store. Does this help to narrow down the issue?

```
SIGSEGV
CoreData_PFfastQueueRelease


0   WIT Premium 0x0019e36e  testflight_backtrace
1   WIT Premium 0x0019da02  TFSignalHandler
2   libsystem_c.dylib   0x3afd7e92  _sigtramp
3   CoreData    0x32d06de8  _PFfastQueueRelease
4   CoreData    0x32ce6eec  -[NSManagedObject release]
5   CoreFoundation  0x32e40310  CFRelease
6   CoreFoundation  0x32f1b433  __CFBasicHashDrain
7   CoreFoundation  0x32e403d0  CFRelease
8   CoreData    0x32cb0d0e  -[_NSFaultingMutableSet dealloc]
9   CoreData    0x32cb51a4  -[_NSNotifyingWrapperMutableSet dealloc]
10  libobjc.A.dylib 0x3ab56488  _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv
11  CoreFoundation  0x32e42440  _CFAutoreleasePoolPop
12  Foundation  0x3378c6da  -[__NSOperationInternal start]
13  Foundation  0x33804be2  __block_global_6
14  libdispatch.dylib   0x3af7111e  _dispatch_call_block_and_release
15  libdispatch.dylib   0x3af7f258  _dispatch_root_queue_drain
16  libdispatch.dylib   0x3af7f3b8  _dispatch_worker_thread2
17  libsystem_c.dylib   0x3afa5a10  _pthread_wqthread
18  libsystem_c.dylib   0x3afa58a3  start_wqthread
```

Comment: Can't tell from what you've posted so far. Where do the objects get created? You look them up in this code but don't create them. Also what does `operation` do? You're passing your managed objects off to some block that could be doing anything.

Comment: The objects are created in the `operation` block and this is a find-or-create pattern similar to that described in the Apple documentation. I'll update my question with some relevant code.

Comment: Hey Daniel you seem to be accessing the objectID property of self.player on a different thread to the one where the object was created. I suggest you store the objectID in an ivar before you run your background thread block. I don't know whether that will help with the issues you are experiencing but I just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: In the same way object ID is passed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8646950/120497)?

Comment: I'll make this change. Does anyone know if this might make a difference to the dupes issue? I'm also considering using `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects` but I'd like to know why that might be necessary and why it would make a difference before I blindly employ it.

Comment: I am having the exactly same issue with multi-threaded core data. And mine happens when the app performs a background fetch