# NSManagedObjectContext(): `init()` was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -initWithConcurrencyType

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I was working through [Core Data Stack in Swift - Demystified](http://siki.io/core-data-stack/) but when I got to the line

```
self.context = NSManagedObjectContext()
```

I got the warning

```
`init()` was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -initWithConcurrencyType: instead
```

I see that I can do one of the following for `self.context =`

```
NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.ConfinementConcurrencyType)
NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
```

but since `ConfinementConcurrencyType` is also deprecated now that leaves me `MainQueueConcurrencyType` and `PrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. What is the difference between these two and how should I choose which one to use? I read [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html), but I didn't really understand.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637921/core-datas-nsprivatequeueconcurrencytype-and-sharing-objects-between-threads) helps you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You essentially will always have at least 1 context with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and many contexts with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` is used typically for saving or fetching things to core data in the background (like if attempting to sync records with a Web Service).

The `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` creates a context associated with the main queue which is perfect for use with `NSFetchedResultsController`.

The default core data stack uses a single context with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, but you can create a much better app by leveraging multiple `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` to do any work that does not affect the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I use `PrivateQueueConcurrencyType` for all of contexts? I assume that it may cause odd behavior or may cause crash as well.

Comment: You should not use `PrivateQueueConcurrencyType` for any work that must be done on the main queue. You should always use `MainQueueConcurrencyType` with an `NSFetchedResultsController`. A `PrivateQueueConcurrencyType` uses a background thread, so keep that tin mind.

Answer (score 8):

Replace these two function with the following one:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
    }()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```